# Run interactive 'master' PowerShell script on local PC as well as remote PCs and log

Tags: powershell, server, interactive, administration

I have a massive (983 line) interactive PowerShell script that I wrote to manage pretty much all aspects of a local server. I have a text file with a list of servers. I want to get crazy with it.

**Text File Contents:**

```
Server1Name
Server2Name
```

**PowerShell Interactive Menu:**

```
Write-Host "Welcome to the environment control script."
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "What would you like to do? Select the number:"
Write-Host "========================================================================="
Write-Host "1. Create a backup of the environment (existing servers)"
Write-Host "2. Backup environment and deploy updated environment (existing servers)"
Write-Host "3. Deploy new environment including IIS (clean servers)"
Write-Host "4. Deploy just IIS (clean servers)"
Write-Host "5. Remove Build w/ backup and cleanup IIS (existing servers)"
Write-Host "6. Remove Build w/out backup and cleanup IIS (existing servers)"
Write-Host "7. Remove and cleanup only IIS (existing servers)"
Write-Host "8. Deploy new DLL's (existing servers)"
Write-Host "9. [EXIT]" -foregroundcolor "yellow"
Write-Host " "
```

**Purpose:**

Trying to get away from having 1000 batch files on my servers

**Example:**

I run script on "Master" server and there are 10 other servers in the text file. At first, the script is ONLY running on the master server. Once I pick option 6, a command is run to do the same commands across all of the 11 servers (master + 10 others).

I know how to run the same script across servers if it was say a simple file copy or service reset (no interaction from the user) using stuff like `invoke-command` or `enter-pssession`,etc...however, in my case I'll have to remote to each server because it's interactive...unless there is a way to do this?

Also, if possible, enable logging so I can confirm that each PC ran the script and did everything successfully. Right now, I have it starting a transcript and stopping at the end. Works great locally.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update: 3/8/16**

So, @Cobster has helped me out and we are 99% there.

Using the follow code, it looks like the script is attempting to run, however there is one more issue.

```
$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers 
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock ${function:Backup} -AsJob

If you want a different job for each machine, you can do the following:

$jobs = $sessions | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command -Session $_ -ScriptBlock ${function:Backup} -AsJob } 
Wait-Job -Job $jobs
```

The issue is that when this is done, the invoke-command doesn't seem to import all of my previously declared variables at the top of my script (which includes virtually ALL of my paths, etc. because they are not defined within that function.

This results in a bunch of these types of errors (7 to be exact, one for each of my test-path checks before performing a step):

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
    + PSComputerName        : *ServerName*
```

*Solution:*

Use `-ArgumentList $variable1, $variable2` in the `invoke-command` and

`param
(
$variable1,
$variable2
)` method within the function...courtesy of Cobster.

Comment: Main post updated, with the help of a member got most of it worked out, however running into seemingly one last hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke-Command can be run in the background by using the -AsJob switch.

Logging is also possible by using the Receive-Job cmdlet to get the output of each of the background jobs upon completion.

Comment: Thanks @Cobster. I finally got around to trying this (was put on another project temporarily).

When I run the following command, it doesn't seem to actually do anything. It doesn't error, but it doesn't actually run the backup function, for example.    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock ${function:Backup} -AsJob

Comment: Is there any output or errors when `Receive-Job` is invoked on these jobs?

Comment: I ran the following from my master script @Cobster...I selected option 1 (to create a backup).

`$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Servers` followed by `$j = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:Backup}}` followed by `$j` and then by `$results = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($j) Recieve-Job -Job $j} -ArgumentList $j`. I got an error saying: **Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ScriptBlock' because it is null.** This showed up twice followed by messages stating that **'Recieve-Job' is not a valid cmdlet** for each server (2 total right now)

Comment: Ah the problem is with the `${function:Backup}` script block.  You need to pass this as a variable to the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock.  `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { param ($s) Start-Job -ScriptBlock $s } -ArgumentList ${function:Backup}`

Comment: Hmm...that make sense @Cobster. I altered it and got two messages (for each server) saying `cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the value **prints out my whole function here** of type 'System.String' to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock'`...

Also has the two receive-job errors from before as well.

Comment: So the issue is that the variable must be a script block.  `${function:[name]}` is the string version of the function.  Perhaps `-ArgumentList { &${function:Backup} }` would work.  This creates a wrapper script block and invokes the string with `&`.

Comment: It didn't list my whole function this time, but did give pretty much the same error. @Cobster

Comment: Perhaps a script block cannot be marshalled via remoting.  Try the following `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { param ($s) Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & $s } } -ArgumentList ${function:Backup}`. If that doesn't work try `{ iex $s }`

Comment: Okay, so that didn't result in errors (still getting the receive-job not valid cmdlet error though). However, it didn't actually run my backup function. I tried both variations of your last suggestion. It's like it sees the function now but it never actually enters it as it didn't even print some of the Write-Hosts I have...@Cobster

Comment: Sounds like progress.  So I'm assuming the script is now loaded in context, you should be able to invoke it by calling the function.  `-ScriptBock { & $s; Backup }`

Comment: Once I fixed the `ScriptBock` to be `ScriptBlock` :P...I got the following `The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced a object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, script block or CommandInfo object.` Got that twice and also one saying that my function name `Backup` was not a valid cmdlet @Cobster. Definitely progress, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105275/discussion-between-cobster-and-ilya).

Comment: Added more to the discussion.

Comment: I updated the main post @Cobster...I think I found the last hurdle, just not sure how to get over it.

Comment: Hey @Cobster...running into a small issue. Please check the chat when you get a minute.